# Are there any aircraft used in part 121 (aka scheduled airline) operations that do not require a type rating to fly?

Tags: airline-operations, airline-pilot, type-ratings

Inspired by [KeithS's question about ATPLs and category/class ratings](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16940/how-much-knowledge-experience-can-be-transferred-between-different-categories-cl), I figured I'd throw another type-rating/airline-operations puzzler at you: are there any aircraft currently in scheduled airline service (i.e. operated under part 121) which would *not* require a type rating to fly?  (I know part 135 operators often fly small aircraft due to the nature of their operation, with more intermittent or even on-demand service and the smaller locales they fly into.)

Comment: FYI: [Part 121 is defined as](http://av-info.faa.gov/Definitions.asp) operating "any turbojet powered airplanes, or airplanes having a passenger-seat configuration of **more than 9 passenger seats**, excluding each crewmember seat, or airplanes having a payload capacity of **more than 7,500 lb.**" So you are looking for non-turbojet aircraft with **payloads** over 7,500 lb or more than 9 seats, and  MGTOW less than 12,500 lb. None have been posted so far.

Comment: @fooot -- Beech 99s and 100s and MU-2s fit into that box, at least when used in pax service.

Comment: Yes, they are in that window. I haven't found any in 121 service though.

Comment: @fooot -- that's interesting that the 99 is no longer in 121 service whatsoever; I'll do some more research on this.

Comment: Also -- FAR/CAR DHC-6 operations do not require a type rating, best I can tell (the Twotter's MTOW is exactly 12,500lbs); EASA takes a dim view of operating *any* turbine-powered aircraft w/o a type rating, though, apparently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cape air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Air#History) has a fleet of 83 Cessna 402s, some of which are involved in its Part 121 operation.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're thinking about passengers, not freight, but [Fedex is a part 121 operator](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/cmo/fedex/) that [operates the Cessna 208 (Caravan)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FedEx_Express#Fleet), which [does not require a type rating](http://registry.faa.gov/TypeRatings/) in the US.

Regional airlines in Hawaii and Alaska also operate the 208, but they seem to be part 135 operations.

Comment: Is Fedex actually operating those caravans on their certificate?  All of the caravans I can think of in Fedex paint are operated by smaller 135 carriers (e.g. Wiggins air).  The planes are dry-leased to the feeder carriers.

Comment: @casey Good question, I really have no idea how or if it's possible to check that.

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FedEx_Express#FedEx_Feeder) all of their prop aircraft are dry leased to contract carriers.

Answer (score 0):

[Cape Air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Air) seems to be a Part 121 carrier, and since they fly the Cessna 402, that might be an answer.