# Is there a list of part 121 and/or 135 operators?

Tags: faa-regulations, airline-operations

While looking into [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16949/62), I found a [list](http://www.transportation.gov/policy/aviation-policy/certificated-air-carriers-list) of certificated air carriers on the US Department of Transportation website (there's [a list](http://www.transportation.gov/policy/aviation-policy/commuter-air-carriers-list) of commuter air carriers too). But, the list doesn't say if each one operates under part 121 or part 135, which the DoT [seems to consider](http://www.transportation.gov/policy/aviation-policy/licensing/US-carriers) an FAA question anyway:

> As noted above, the economic authority issued to air carriers by the
>   Department is separate from the safety authority (commonly referred to
>   as Part 135 or Part 121 Operations Specifications) granted to them by
>   the Federal Aviation Administration (FAA).  For safety authority
>   application procedures and related questions, air carriers should
>   contact the appropriate FAA flight standard district office based upon
>   the geographical location of the air carrier

The FAA site has a [lot of information](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/atos/air_carrier/) about part 121 operations, but at least as far as I could see there's no list of 121 or 135 carriers anywhere on their site.

Is there a list somewhere of current part 121 and/or 135 operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [FAA website](http://av-info.faa.gov/dd_sublevel.asp?Folder=%5CAirOperators), there is a list of Air Operator to download. You can choose the format you like and open it in your favourite spreadsheet. How to delimit the file depends on your program and out of scope here.

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a list, but you can search for an airline [here](http://av-info.faa.gov/OpCert.asp).

There is a link on the page to [definitions of the terms](http://av-info.faa.gov/Definitions.asp). Basically, "domestic" and "flag" are FAR 121 operations, and "commuter" is FAR 135 operations.

[There is also an unofficial database here](http://www.aviationdb.com/Aviation/AirOperatorQuery.shtm) that will tell you which FAR an airline operates under.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a list of every Part 135 aircraft registered and their operators.
https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/.../135Aircraft.xlsx

Comment: Please re-post the link... what is on the page doesn't work.